# jquery if/else statement running all arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery

Question: Why is my code running the slide toggle feature on every nav click instead of only the ones assigned to toggle?

When the user clicks on the navigation each nav is assigned a value.

Based on the number value the code should run a specific animation into the targeted page.

The music and fashion page have both slide toggles.

While the parties page has a fade out.

I noticed that the parties page continues to slide toggle, even when i took off any fade out/in the current page still slide toggles.

Is there something wrong with the code? How can i do this better?

```
$('.nav').click(function () {
    var abc = $(this).attr('data-value');
    console.log(abc);
    if (abc == 0) {
        $('#fashion-page').show(function () {
            $grid1.masonry('layout');
            $('#blog').addClass('activer');
            $('.current-page').slideToggle(600, function () {
                $('.page').removeClass('current-page');
                $('#fashion-page').addClass('current-page');
            });
        });

    } else if (abc == 1) {
        $('#party-page').show(function () {
            $('.current-page').fadeOut(400, function () {
                $('.page').removeClass('current-page');
                $('#party-page').addClass('current-page');
            });
        });

    } else if (abc == 2) {
        $('#music-page').show(function () {
            $('.current-page').slideToggle(600, function () {
                $('.page').removeClass('current-page');
                $('#music-page').addClass('current-page');
            });
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Could you provide us a fiddle so we can test ?

Answer (score -2):

Sorry , it was because I had accidentally used the same ID for to different buttons. Once changed everything worked smoothly.

Comment: Do the "Answer to my own question" function.